# Problem with multiple CSS pie + overlay

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

This is an IE7/IE8 issue --

I'm trying to load an overlay beneath a CSS pie object. The object is partially covered by the overlay until you scroll a bit.

Here is a link, http://lab.atworkinthecloud.com/csspie-index/index.php (click on the "+View History" link to trigger the dropdown with overlay)

The funny think is it works fine with only one or two objects on the page --

But with multiple objects on the page things get crazy.

http://lab.atworkinthecloud.com/csspie-index/index1.php

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, make sure that you have read this page:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/
very carefully, especially the part about wrapping/setting position:relative/absolute.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was looking for a better explanation of how CSSpie works. Hopefully it will provide answers or at least a better understanding of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery `.delegate()` function in place of `.live()`. [jQuery delegate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) shows you just how similar they are, just delegate is more efficient.

EDIT: also, try upgrading to a newer version of jQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade to a newer version of jQuery yet, I think that would solve a lot of the issues I'm having.